# IllegalStateException in AsyncTask. The content of adapter has changed but listview did not receive a notification

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, illegalstateexception

I am working on TCP socket. I receive data for every 1 sec from server and I need to display it on screen in ListView. 
For this I used AsyncTask.

But I am frequently getting IllegalStateException error

[image]

My code:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finalizer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (navBool) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                new RetriveStock().execute(); // AsyncTask.
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        handler.post(finalizer);
    }
}; 
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000);
```

// AsyncTask class

```
public class RetriveStock extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        message = client.clientReceive(1); // Here I receive data from server and stores it in "message" string variable.
        printJson(); // FUNCTION WHICH UPDATE VALUES IN 'obj' OBJECT
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateList();// FUNCTION WHICH UPDATE THE LISTVIEW UI.
                adb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                if (adb != null) {
                    lv.invalidateViews();
                    lv.setAdapter(adb);
                    adb.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    lv.requestLayout();

                }


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

// function which update values in JSON.

```
    public void printJson() {
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(message);

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


            String symbol = json.getString("Symbol_En");
            User obj = new User();
            boolean checkSymbol = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                obj = list.get(j);
                if (obj.getSymbol().equalsIgnoreCase(symbol)) {
                    checkSymbol = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!checkSymbol) {
                obj = new User();
                obj.Symbol_En = json.getString("Symbol_En");
                obj.Symbol_Ar = json.getString("Symbol_Ar");
                obj.AskPrice = json.getString("Ask");
                obj.BidPrice = json.getString("Bid");
                obj.AskQuantity = json.getString("AskQuantity");
                obj.High = json.getString("High");
                obj.Low = json.getString("Low");
                obj.Open = json.getString("Open");
                obj.Close = json.getString("Close");
                obj.PerChange = json.getString("PerChange");
                obj.NetChange = json.getString("NetChange");
                obj.Volume = json.getString("Volume");
                obj.Ltp = json.getString("LTP");
                obj.TimeStamp = json.getString("TimeStamp");
                obj.symbolId = json.getString("Id");

                    list.add(obj);
            } else {

                obj.Symbol_En = json.getString("Symbol_En");
                obj.AskPrice = json.getString("Ask");
                obj.BidPrice = json.getString("Bid");
                obj.High = high + "";
                obj.Low = low + "";
                obj.Open = json.getString("Open");
                obj.Close = json.getString("Close");
                obj.PerChange = json.getString("PerChange");
                obj.NetChange = json.getString("NetChange");
                obj.Volume = json.getString("Volume");
                obj.Ltp = json.getString("LTP");
                obj.TimeStamp = json.getString("TimeStamp");
                obj.symbolId = json.getString("Id");

            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

// function which update LISTVIEW UI.

```
public void updateList() {
        adb = new ArrayAdapter<User>(DefaultMarketWatch.this,
                R.layout.rssitemview, list) {

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                try {
                    if (null == view) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) DefaultMarketWatch.this
                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        view = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitemview, null);
                    }
                    final User u = list.get(position);
                    if (null != u) {
                        final TextView title = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.symbol);
                        final TextView persend = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.persent);
                        final TextView ltp = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.ltp);
                        final TextView high = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.high);
                        final TextView low = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.low);
                        final TextView persendBold = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.persent_bold);
                        final TextView persendSup = (TextView) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.persent_sup);

                                ltp.setText(u.getLtp());
                                title.setText(u.getSymbol());
                                high.setText(u.getHigh());
                                low.setText(u.getLow());
                                    persend.setText(u.getPerChange());

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return view;

            }

        };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your log says

```
The content of the adapter is changed but listview did not receive notification. make sure content of your adapter is not modified from background thread but only from ui thread.
```

You have  `updateList() // FUNCTION WHICH UPDATE THE LISTVIEW UI`in `doInBackground`. `doInbackground` is invoked on the background thread. You need to update ui on the Ui thread.

Use `runOnUiThread` which is method of activity or return result in `doInbackground` and update listview in `onPostExecute`

Comment: Firstly I have done the same. but returning the same result. IllegalStateException. Now I modified my updateList() with runOnUiThread. Please have a look.

Comment: @user2085965 no still wrong try putting `updateList` in `runOnUiThread` and call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh listview on updatation

Comment: @user2085965 secondly don't post snap shot post the stack trace here instead. select the exception part and use the button next to verbose at the top right of the screen shot and post the exception here

Comment: Still getting same result. I put updateList() in runOnUiThread and removed inside the function. Please look my code I have updated as you said.

Comment: @user2085965 post the stack trace for further assistance

Comment: Is it necessary to put onPostExecute code also in runOnUiThread.?

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan. One more mistake which I have made is setting the timer repetition to 1000. Why I'm getting IllegalStateException means timer calling AsyncTask for every 1 sec irrespective of the present running task completion. It was solved when I set timer value to 5 sec.

Comment: @user2085965 that is what i said in the discussion if you remember i recommended a executor if you want parallel execution. it am still not sure having asynctask run in a timer is good. a service would be better i guess